# Poker deck class /w generator function and list comprehensions

Tags: python, object-oriented, playing-cards, generator

There are multiple aspects in the code I do not really like. `[card for card in ...]` looks really lame, also `[x.pop() for i in range(y)]`. I'm looking forward for any recommendation.

```
from random import shuffle 

class Deck(object):
    suits = range(4)
    ranks = range(13)

    @classmethod
    def generator(cls, suits, ranks):
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                yield({'suit': suit, 'rank': rank})

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [card for card in Deck.generator(Deck.suits, Deck.ranks)]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, amount):
        return [self.cards.pop() for i in range(amount)]

print Deck().deal(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[card for card in Deck.generator(…)]` could be written as `list(Deck.generator(…))`.

Better yet, use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
self.cards = [
    {'suit': suit, 'rank': rank}
    for suit, rank in itertools.product(xrange(4), xrange(13))
]
```

In Python 2, you should be using `xrange()` rather than `range()`.

It's probably worth defining a `Card` class.  At some point, you'll want to have suits that are named rather than numbered, and ranks A, J, Q, K rather than 0..12.

To deal multiple cards, you can slice the list instead of popping one card at a time:

```
def deal(self, n):
    hand = self.cards[-1 : -n-1 : -1]
    self.cards = self.cards[: -n]
    return hand
```

Comment: 1, `itertools.product()` and the proposed list comprehension looks great, thank you for that. 

2, I will look into that `xrange()` topic - I already saw it, but did not pay attention yet.

3, I do have a Card class with overridden `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__eq__` functions, but I did not want to clutter the question with it.

4, I decided not to use list slicing for the sake of simplicity, I will reconsider.

Thank you :)

Comment: about the `xrange()` vs. `range()` subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/97530/1486768

Comment: Unless your lists are going in the millions of items, which they clearly are not here, I'd stick with `range`, mostly for portability. I similarly don't use any of the `iterxxx` methods of Python 2 `dict`s for the exact same reason.

Comment: I can't resist noting that although the slicing is probably more efficient, it sort of violates the poker rule that cards must be dealt off the top of the deck, one at a time.  The `.pop()` route is arguably the best simulation of this poker rule.  You don't want any virtual card sharks accusing you of cheating... :-)

Comment: @CurtF. The way I wrote it, the slice is reversed, so the result should be the same.

Comment: @Jaime if portability is a concern why not just use six and/or a user defined compatability.py?